# Clicking Android Spinner throws NullPointerException only on emulators

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, emulation

I have a **Spinner** with dynamic items. By clicking the spinner, it will load a new set of items. It works perfectly on actual devices. But when I run the application on any emulator, it throws **NullPointerException** after I click on the spinner.
I haven't found any solution from anyone. Can someone help me, please?

Here is the error from LogCat (The error is the same for all emulators of different devices and API levels -- BUT DOES NOT OCCUR ON REAL DEVICES.). As you see, it does not point to any line of my code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:534)
at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:485)
at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:449)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
...
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is how I put the items on the list.

```
List<MyObject> itemsList = getItemsFromMySource();
if (itemsList!=null && itemsList.size() > 0) {
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My CustomListAdapter uses the default layout for spinners.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

    public CustomListAdapter (Context context, List<MyObject> listItems) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listItems);
        setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int item, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);

        final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setText(getItem(item).getItemName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int item, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);

        final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setText(getItem(item).getItemName());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never set your spinner adapter to null!

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(null);
```

I did that because I needed it in my application's feature. So I just used `mySpinner.setEnabled(false)` to compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Here the content of the android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/assets/res/any/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml
**
** Copyright 2008, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Please create a new file named "simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml" in you res/layout folder. Then copy/paste the previous code in it.

Then, replace `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` by `R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` in your `CustomListAdapter`.

The main idea here is that maybe your emulators don't have the android simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml integrated, so by copying it in your app, you prevent `inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);` of returning null and then to get a NullPointerException.

I don't if it will work but it is worth trying.